# Problem creating foreign keys in mySql

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys, myisam, cascading-deletes

I created a foreign key in my sql by the following statemnt..

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `id`) 
REFERENCES `user_login` (`user_id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ;
```

The creation appears to succeed then after that I execute a delete statement

```
DELETE From user_login WHERE user_id = 1576;
```

yet in users the row still exists that is referencing that. I open up the mysql workbench and it doesn't show any signs that the foreign key was created. Does anyone know why this would be? Or what I am doing wrong? It is a one-to-one relationship in the two tables.

Comment: Does the ALTER TABLE statement return an error -- something to indicate it wasn't applied?  DDL statements implicitly commit, so it's not a matter with transactions.

Comment: @OMG Ponies No, it doesn't return an error, it just says 1306 row(s) affected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table may be in MyISAM format, which does not support foreign keys.

Try converting it to InnoDB first:

```
alter table users engine=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Good call what engine should i use? I'm knew to the MySQL world, I have always use MS SQL in the past

Comment: Why would it default to an engine that doesn't allow FK's?

Comment: I guess this is for forward compatibility reasons

Answer (score 1):

You have to also make sure that both `users.id` and `user_login.user_id` have an index each.

Comment: They both do. Both are primary keys in their respective tables.

Comment: Indexes have nothing to do with referential integrity constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this code in your **Mysql script editor** and run. You will have two tables **categories** and **products** these tables having **cat_id** as **foreign key**.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS dbdemo;

USE dbdemo;

CREATE TABLE categories(
   cat_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
   cat_name varchar(255) not null,
   cat_description text
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE products(
   prd_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
   prd_name varchar(355) not null,
   prd_price decimal,
   cat_id int not null,
   FOREIGN KEY fk_cat(cat_id)
   REFERENCES categories(cat_id)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE
   ON DELETE RESTRICT
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```