# Database foreign key constraint doesn't work?

Tags: database, foreign-keys

I have created a simple database using Dezign:

[image]

This is the output:

```
CREATE TABLE `Entity1` (
    `Attribute_1` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_Entity1` PRIMARY KEY (`Attribute_1`)
);

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# Add table "Entity2"                                                    #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------- #

CREATE TABLE `Entity2` (
    `Attribute_2` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Attribute_11` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_Entity2` PRIMARY KEY (`Attribute_2`, `Attribute_11`)
);

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# Foreign key constraints                                                #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------- #

ALTER TABLE `Entity2` ADD CONSTRAINT `Entity1_Entity2` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`Attribute_11`) REFERENCES `Entity1` (`Attribute_1`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

The `Attribute_11` in `Entity2` refers to `Attribute_1` in `Entity1`. However, when I import this into my MySQL 5.1 server, I am still able to insert rows into `Entity2` even if the `Attribute_11` field doesn't match any of the entries in the `Entity1` table.

How can I restrict this using Dezign? Why is the foreign key constraint not enough?

Comment: I believe this is related to the *engine* you use in MySQL. MySQL help says you have to use Innodb to enable foreign keys. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: Ah thanks, apparently all tables are MyISAM by default. If you'd add this as an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: Actually, I think it should be marked as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4769357/422353